# Unusual std::vector::size() response

Tags: c++, stdvector

I think I am struggling with an issue similar to this one:
[C++ std::vector::size() changes its state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730549/c-stdvectorsize-changes-its-state)
but am unable to make the connection to my current issue.

I am seeking to create a vector of pointers to objects. This is done because I wish to create a subset to a larger collection of objects to operate on. My code is

```
mp::CellSet generate_1D_cellset(geom::NodeSet &nodes){
/*Generate cells from an (ordered in terms of position) list of 1D nodes*/

    std::vector<mp::Cell*> cell_array;
    cell_array.resize(nodes.number-1);
    std::string name = "Linear1D";

    for(int i=0; i<(nodes.number-1); i++){
        //std::cout << i;
        cell_array[i] = generate_1D_cell(i,name,nodes);
    }

    mp::CellSet cells = mp::CellSet(cell_array);

    return cells;
}
```

when I query (using gdb) `cell_array.size()` immediately after creation or after the resize I get the answer I expect (2 for my test problem) but if I query the same response at the beginning of the for loop I find that `cell_array.size()` gives a very unexpected value (very large).

Why does the length of the vector change? Is the pointer to the Cell object going out of scope somehow?

Comment: Do you have optimizations turned on? Print it with cout/printf from your code, calling the function from gdb is a crap shoot.

Comment: Maybe try to check using debug output statements whether the problem is GDB incorrect reporting

Comment: Jason C I think you are right. I took a look at that question and now I am seeing the expected response. If you want to resubmit as an answer I will mark yours as correct.